# How to correctly design page objects using theintern testing framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, intern

I'm creating functional tests using [theintern](http://theintern.github.io) framework. I want to model my tests using "page objects" since I would like the code to be reusable.

In the original [documentation](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#page-objects), there is a very simplified sample that shows how to create a page object with one method called 'login'.
In this example, all the logic of this method is inside the method itself.

I would like to create a page object that represents a page a little more complex than a login page, and be able to reuse components inside the page for different actions.

Here's an example of what I want to do :

```
// in tests/support/pages/IndexPage.js
define(function (require) {
  // the page object is created as a constructor
  // so we can provide the remote Command object
  // at runtime
  function IndexPage(remote) {
    this.remote = remote;
  }

  function enterUsername(username) {
    return this.remote
      .findById('login').click().type(username).end();
  }
  function enterPassword(pass) {
    return this.remote
      .findById('password').click().type(pass).end();
  }

  IndexPage.prototype = {
    constructor: IndexPage,

    // the login function accepts username and password
    // and returns a promise that resolves to `true` on
    // success or rejects with an error on failure
    login: function (username, password) {
      return this
        .enterUsername(username)
        .enterPassword(password)
        .findById('loginButton')
        .click()
        .end()
        // then, we verify the success of the action by
        // looking for a login success marker on the page
        .setFindTimeout(5000)
        .findById('loginSuccess')
        .then(function () {
          // if it succeeds, resolve to `true`; otherwise
          // allow the error from whichever previous
          // operation failed to reject the final promise
          return true;
        });
    },

    // …additional page interaction tasks…
  };

  return IndexPage;
});
```

Notice how I created the `enterUsername` and `enterPassword` methods.
This is because I would like to reuse these methods in other tests of the same page object. The problem with this is that I can't chain these methods, it doesn't work.

The methods that can be chained all return the `Command` object, but when I chain my methods, they aren't defined on the `Command` method so the first method gets called (in my example this is `enterUsername`), but then the second fails, obviously since `enterPassword` isn't defined on the `Command` object.

I would like to know how I can model my Page Objects so I can reuse parts of the code within the page object, but still have a nice fluent syntax like this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use your methods as `then` callback handlers, like:

```
function enterName(username) {
    return function () {
        return this.parent.findById('login').click().type(username);
    }
}

function enterPassword(password) {
    return function () {
        return this.parent.findById('password').click().type(pass).end();
    }
}

IndexPage.prototype = {
    constructor: IndexPage,

    login: function (username, password) {
        return this.remote
            .then(enterUsername(username))
            .then(enterPassword(password))
            .findById('loginButton')
            // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to follow up on this with a few questions:
- As shown doesn't work for me unless I use something like `enterName(username).call(this, function(){...` because the AMD module only includes IndexPage. Is it alright to just define these on the prototype?

- Why do the intern docs completely clobber/redefine the prototype rather than adding individual properties? I thought this was an antipattern.

I'll add these as my own question if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, the helper function calls shouldn't have been using `this` in the example since they're not on the prototype. But yes, it would be fine to include them on the prototype instead. The Intern docs describe one way of implementing page objects, via subclassing Command. However, having helper functions that can be used in a normal Command chain typically ends up being easier to implement and more flexible than subclassing Command.